# request url using kivy

Tags: python, django, request, kivy

I want to get some data from app writen in django, using kivy, django server is on 127.0.0.1:8000. I cant see any messages and the result is None, my request script is

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import urllib

def success(req, result):
    print 'ok'
def fail(req, result):
    print 'fail'

params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue',
    '@action': 'show'})
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept': 'text/plain'}

UrlRequest('http://127.0.0.1:8000', on_success=success, on_failure=fail, on_error=fail, req_body=params, req_headers=headers)
```

Comment: Do the server responds to the same request done via `curl`?

Answer (score 4):

If you run the code not in event loop, it does not work.

To run it without GUI event loop, use [`UrlRequest.wait`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html#kivy.network.urlrequest.UrlRequest.wait) method:

```
...
req = UrlRequest('http://daum.net', on_success=success, on_failure=fail,
                 on_error=fail, req_body=params, req_headers=headers)
req.wait()
```